# Imagemagick images next to each other with proper margin

Tags: image, command, imagemagick, margin

I am trying to create a png file with a transparent background, in which I put images next to each other.

My command so far is this:

```
convert --% -bordercolor none -background none -gravity center logo.png -border 5x5 ( img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg -border 5x5 +append ) ( img4.jpg img5.jpg img6.jpg -border 5x5 +append ) -append -border 5x5 -resize 720x480 output.png
```

it creates me this image

[image]

how do I have to change my command to make the image appear as following?

(I made the background grey so one can see the white text, the background shall be transparent later on)

[image]

I tried Mark Setchells suggestion the command so far looks like this:

> ```
> convert -background none -bordercolor none -gravity west \
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\Img_1.jpg label:"1" +swap -append label:"text 1" -append -write miff:- +delete \
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\Img_2.jpg label:"2" +swap -append label:"text 2" -append -write miff:- +delete \
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\Img_3.jpg label:"3" +swap -append label:"text 3" -append -write miff:- +delete \
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\Img_4.jpg label:"4" +swap -append label:"text 4" -append -write miff:- +delete \
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\Img_5.jpg label:"5" +swap -append label:"text 5" -append -write miff:- +delete \
> C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\Img_6.jpg label:"6" +swap -append label:"text 6" -append miff:- |
> montage -set label '' miff:- -background pink -tile 3x2 -geometry +15+5 miff:- |
> convert -size 800x500 xc:gray80 -gravity center miff:- -composite -gravity north C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\logo.png -geometry +0+30 -composite C:\xampp\htdocs\app\storage\images\result.png
> ```

Comment: What is `--%` and what OS are you using?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using windows, right now I am not quiet sure what --% meant, but if I use my command without it, it does not work properly

Comment: Do you now want to space the images, add the numbers and the text all in Imagemagick? I see you also mention Imaagick in the tags; where does that come into it? You need to decide on what code you are going to use as it can have an effect on the answer.

Comment: @Bonzo yes I do

Comment: @Bonzo now I see what you mean, yes you are correct that is a wrong tag I deleted it just now, I want an imagemagick command as an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it many ways. Here is one:

#### Method 1

```
#!/bin/bash
convert -background none -bordercolor none -gravity west \
   \( 1.png label:"1" +swap -append label:"text 1" -append -border 5x5 \) \
   \( 2.png label:"2" +swap -append label:"text 2" -append -border 5x5 \) +append \
   \( 3.png label:"3" +swap -append label:"text 3" -append -border 5x5 \) +append \
 \( \
   \( 4.png label:"4" +swap -append label:"text 4" -append -border 5x5 \) \
   \( 5.png label:"5" +swap -append label:"text 5" -append -border 5x5 \) +append \
   \( 6.png label:"6" +swap -append label:"text 6" -append -border 5x5 \) +append \
 \) -append  \
 -gravity center -extent 800x550 \
 -gravity north logo.png -geometry +0+30 -composite result.png
```

[image]

#### Method 2

This way you can use the first `convert` command to put the labels above and below each image and then stream all 6 labelled images into `montage` to do the grid layout (on pink) for you and from there back into another `convert` to create the gray background canvas and write the logo on at the top.

```
#!/bin/bash
convert -background none -bordercolor none -gravity west \
   1.png label:"1" +swap -append label:"text 1" -append -write miff:- +delete \
   2.png label:"2" +swap -append label:"text 2" -append -write miff:- +delete \
   3.png label:"3" +swap -append label:"text 3" -append -write miff:- +delete \
   4.png label:"4" +swap -append label:"text 4" -append -write miff:- +delete \
   5.png label:"5" +swap -append label:"text 5" -append -write miff:- +delete \
   6.png label:"6" +swap -append label:"text 6" -append miff:- |
   montage -set label '' miff:- -background pink -tile 3x2 -geometry +15+5 miff:- |
   convert -size 800x500 xc:gray80 -gravity center miff:- -composite -gravity north logo.png -geometry +0+30 -composite result.png
```

[image]

Sorry, I have no idea or understanding why Windows is so poor at parsing the command, but after much fiddling around, the following seems to work - I have no idea why!

```
convert -background none -bordercolor none -gravity west ^
   1.png label:"1" +swap -append label:"text 1" -append -write miff:- +delete ^
   2.png label:"2" +swap -append label:"text 2" -append -write miff:- +delete ^
   3.png label:"3" +swap -append label:"text 3" -append -write miff:- +delete ^
   4.png label:"4" +swap -append label:"text 4" -append -write miff:- +delete ^
   5.png label:"5" +swap -append label:"text 5" -append -write miff:- +delete ^
   6.png label:"6" +swap -append label:"text 6" -append miff:- | montage -set label "" miff:- ^
   -background pink -tile 3x2 -geometry +15+5 miff:- | convert -size 800x500 ^
   xc:gray80 -gravity center miff: -composite -gravity north logo.png -geometry +0+30 -composite result.png
```

Comment: thanks I will try this, what does #!/bin/bash stand for

Comment: Oh, it's Linux. If you are on Windows you may have to replace the backslashes with carets (`^`).

Comment: The Logo above is actually an image not a text, sorry my example image is bad

Comment: I get following error if I run that command: In line:1 Character:840 + ... abel:"4" +swap -append label:"text 4" -append -border 5x5 ) `(` C:\... + unexpected Token "("

+ ...  label:"4" +swap -append label:"text 4" -append -border 5x5 )HERE( C:\ ...
+ ...  +swap -append label:"text 6" -append -border 5x5 ) +append `) `-append ...

Comment: The command line does underline the marked brackets and "HERE"

Comment: Ugh! I hate Windows! Are there spaces in your filenames? If so, enclose the entire filename in double quotes (`"C:\Directory with space\file with space.png"`)

Comment: Ok, I have changed it to accommodate your logo being an image in both examples.

Comment: No, all the pipe symbols (`|`) are pipes and they pass the output of one program into the next program as its input.

Comment: how can I copy this code in my console do I need to remove the \ ?

Comment: I edit my question and post the command I used but did not work, if you may have a look at it

Comment: Which example are you using? If the first on Windows you need to change all the \ ( \ ) to ( ) as well. Note I had to add the space after the \ as it would not post here.

Comment: I used the command above I put it into my question but I forgot to replace \ I will do that now and give you are reply

Comment: @Bonzo If I replace \ with () the console gives an error at (), could you show me the command I have to use on windows if I replace the \ please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did not get an error message I posted the command which I used in my question

Comment: Would you like to move in a chat?

Comment: I have finally tried all possible combinations and found one that works!!! Please see the final part of the amended answer. There must be some mad rule about continuation lines and pipes that I don't know. Maybe some Windows-y person will be able to elaborate...

Comment: @MarkSetchell how do I change the command if I do not need the logo but still need the margin/padding

Comment: Change `convert ... -tile 3x2 -geometry +15+5 miff:- | ....` to `convert ... -tile 3x2 -geometry +15+5 result.png`

Comment: so the end of the command looks like this?   `... 6.png label:"6" +swap -append label:"text 6" -append miff:- | montage -set label "" miff:- ^
   -background pink -tile 3x2 -geometry +15+5 result.png`

Comment: I always get a strange error that it ccanot find the image and that he cannot understand the labels(1,2,3,4...), I do have jpg (image)files does that make any difference?

Comment: If your label image is called `1.jpg` then you must use `1.jpg` rather than `1.png`

Comment: The error is gone I forgot that I fixed that already. Now I get this error `montage:exe: missing an iamge filename C:\testimages\result.jpg @ error/montage.c/MontageImageCommand/1790`, result is the image I want to create the path is correct

Comment: Oh ok it works on cmd, but on powershell I still get that error. I got 2 more question how do I change the size of the result.jpg and how can I specify the size of each image

Comment: To change the size of the output image to 200x300, just add `-resize 200x300` immediately before writing the output image. Or use `-resize 200x300^!` if it is ok to distort the image - maybe without the caret.

Comment: To change the size of an input image use `convert ... input1.jpg -resize 200x300 ....`, so, put `-resize 200x300` immediately after loading it.

Comment: strange if I `-resize 720x576 C:\testImages\result.jpg` the output image gets a size of 2010x1208, (thus I gave each image a width of 200x150^!)

Comment: Try making a 100x100 image and then resizing it till you get the idea of how it works... `convert -size 100x100 xc:red -resize 800x400\! result.jpg` then `identify result.jpg` and check the size of your resized 100x100 image. You may need to remove the backslash, or replace it with a caret on Windows.

Comment: So I change the 6 images they have a width of 150x125 now, but my result.jpg is still huge, would you like to see the image and the code?

Comment: What size is huge please?

Comment: How can I add another font here if I try basic '-font XXX' it does not change

Comment: Do you know why this does not work properly if I just use 4 images?